# How to search a nested object using zq?

Tags: filtering

Given this input in a file called `plants.json`

```
{
  "flower": { "rose": 1 },
  "tree": { "spruce": 1, "oak": 2, "oaky": 3 }
}
```

Filter it with `zq` so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "flower": { "rose": 1 },
  "tree": { "oak": 2, "oaky": 3 }
}
```

Effectively filtering a known and named nested object at the key `tree` to match `oak`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zq`'s `put` operator (the `:=`) to redefine `tree` as a filtered search.

```
zq -f json 'tree:=unflatten((over tree | oak))' plants.json
{"flower":{"rose":1},"tree":{"oak":2,"oaky":3}}
```

This does a simple search on keys and values.  If you want to match more precisely, you can use other functions where `| oak` is.

For example, if you have a document that also includes `"soak":4`

```
{
  "flower": { "rose": 1 },
  "tree": { "spruce": 1, "oak": 2, "oaky": 3, "soak": 4 }
}
```

Then this won't work because you'll get *oak and oaky and soak*.  So use `grep()` and a regex for this case.  This example demonstrates how to add the function `grep` to our previous command.

```
zq -f json 'tree:=unflatten((over tree | grep(/^oak/)))' plants.json
{"flower":{"rose":1},"tree":{"oak":2,"oaky":3}}
```

Note that `tree:=unflatten(...)` is the same as saying `put tree:=unflatten(...)` because `put` is an implied operator like `oak` is `search oak`.  Some of the links on zq's doc site are currently broken but it is currently in the [2.6 language overview section](https://zed.brimdata.io/docs/language/overview/#26-implied-operators).